# Count of shows for banner

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have banners on my site. In CMS admin can setup count of shows(`ShowCount`) in day, week, month(`PeriodShowCount`).
I have method for returned banner:

```
   public Banner GetSimpleBanner()
      {                     
           Banner banner =  Database.Banners.Where(b=> b.IsPublish.Value && 
              b.Category.Value == (int)CategoryBanner.SimpleBanner && 
              b.ShowCountAlready < b.ShowCount ).Take(1).FirstOrDefault();

           banner.ShowCountAlready++;            
           return   banner;
      }
```

For example, for banner set 100 shows in month. And I need to clear `ShowCountAlready` when month is over.
What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Put a job running at the end of each month to execute the code that clears the ShowCountAlready property.